# Python: changing string values in lists into ascii values using append

Tags: python, ascii, ord

Im trying to figure out how to produce a list (for each string), a list of ASCII values representing the characters in each of those strings.

EG. changing "hello", "world" so that it looks like:

```
[[104, 101, 108, 108, 111], [119, 111, 114, 108, 100]]
```

Heres my code so far:

```
words = ["hello", "world"]
ascii = []
for word in words:
    ascii_word = []
    for char in word:
        ascii_word.append(ord(char))
    ascii.append(ord(char))

print ascii_word, ascii
```

I know it doesnt work but I am struggling to make it function properly. Any help would be much appreciated. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
words = ["hello", "world"]
ascii = []
for word in words:
    ascii_word = []
    for char in word:
        ascii_word.append(ord(char))
    ascii.append(ascii_word)  # Change this line

print ascii # and only print this.
```

But look into [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and @Shashank's code.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> [[ord(c) for c in w] for w in ['hello', 'world']]
[[104, 101, 108, 108, 111], [119, 111, 114, 108, 100]]
```

This is simply a concise way of writing the following code:

```
outerlist = []
for w in ['hello', 'world']:
    innerlist = []
    for c in w:
        innerlist.append(ord(c))
    outerlist.append(innerlist)
```

Comment: You should explain why that works rather than just giving him code, it will help him learn.